# Why was this question closed?

Tags: support

[Any plans to ban body scanner opt out after Brexit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/141523/4188) I asked a very specific question: whether plans exist or not. I ***did not*** ask what will happen. How on earth can the existence of these plans be a matter of opinion? We have seen people here (Gayot , especially ) who had excellent sources of materials ordinary people would be very hard pressed to find. This is why I asked what I asked. It's just people can't be bothered to read.

Comment: Come on, in the comments there are at least three telling you why we think this question had to be closed.

Comment: None of them has anything to do with the question, it has to do with what people presumed I asked.

Comment: You ask about things to happen after Brexit. While at this time there is still no certainty Brexit will happen and if so, how. Reason enough to close. The other reason also stand. We can guess what is going to happen after Brexit, we can not know.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with all the Brexit travel questions is that no certainty exists *anywhere* in the process, starting from very basic questions such as whether or not the UK and the EU will allow unrestricted flights between each other. Yes, there might be a policy document somewhere deep on Gov.UK which mentions the possibility of removing the body scanners opt out, but what good does it do at this point? Britain might end up staying in the EU eventually or end up accepting EU's policies in body scanners to align airport security between the two regions.

Feel free to reopen this question a few weeks after Brexit actually happens (if it ever does) and I'm sure we could dig up a proper answer then.